# AngularJS Router and ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi I have having trouble getting my router to work.  I have created a page called lookup.html and I've added it to my router file, but it's not loading in the ui-view when I go to the url I've specified in the router.  I've created a plnkr and hope it will help.

http://plnkr.co/edit/II7Mv7jNYENhJHKX1ht5?p=linter

here's my router:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('crm.ma')
    .config(config);

config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login?token',
            data: {
                skipAuth: true
            },
            resolve: {
                valid: function (authService, $stateParams, sessionService, $state) {
                    if (!sessionService.getSession()) {
                        if ($stateParams.token) {
                            sessionService.setSession($stateParams.token);
                        } else {
                            sessionService.removeSession();
                        }
                    }
                    authService.login();
                }
            }
        })

        .state('main', {
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/components/common/layout.html',
            controller: 'mainController as vm',
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Homepage'
            }
        })
        .state('main.index', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
            controller: 'mainController as vm',
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Homepage'
            }
        })            
        .state('search', {
            url: '/search',
            templateUrl: 'app/advancedsearch/advanced-search.html',
            controller: 'advancedsearch.controller as vm',
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Search'
            }

        })
        .state('lookup', {
            url: '/lookup',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/common/lookup.html',
            controller: 'LookUpCtrl as vm',
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Look Up'
            }

        })
        .state('dealer', {
            url: '/dealer',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/common/layout.html',
            controller: 'dealerController as vm',
            data: {
                pageTitle: 'Dealer'
            }
        });;
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}
})();
```

and here is my lookup.html page.

```
<div>
<div>Lookup Results</div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Acc. ID</td>
            <td>Acc. Name</td>
            <td>Acc Address</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>Zip</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td>Parent Name</td>
            <td>Account Type</td>
            <td>Account Status</td>
            <td>Credit Term</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="result in vm.results">
            <td>{{ result.accountId }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountName }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.address }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.state }}</td>
            <td>{{ reuslt.zip }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.parentName }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountType }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountStatus }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountStatus }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.creditTerm }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If any further info is needed please let me know.  I didn't write this, and I'm still a little unsure on how to use the router.

Comment: Please show us what do you have in layout.html.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you has imported angular-route.js and not angular-ui-route.js; they are differents. With angular-route.js you should use:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

And in angular-ui-route.js you should use:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

Another problem maybe is the first line of you router file, it should be like:

```
'use strict';
   angular.module(.........
```

Comment: neither of those are the problem.  I still can't get my pages to show up where I've placed <div ui-view></div>